# Help me about sum of series.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I don't know how to solve this problem.

With $0<p<1$, show that:

$\sum\limits_{z = 0}^\infty  {\left( \begin{array}{l}
r + z\\
z
\end{array} \right){p^{r + 1}}{{\left( {1 - p} \right)}^z}} =1$

Please help me.

Comment: There is a simple argument that uses probabilities. Toss a coin that has probability $p$ of head until we get $r+1$ heads. The term with $z$ in the sum is the probability that the $r+1$-th head occurs at the $r+z+1$-th toss.

Comment: I know. But how it equal 1

Comment: @phuong this explains everything clearly. try to prove by using probability. +1 for Andre Nicolas comment.

Comment: ok. I see sum of probability is 1. Thks

Answer (score 1):

Use the binomial series
$$
(1+x)^\alpha=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{\alpha}{k}x^k
$$
and probably the identity
$$
\binom{\alpha}{k}=\frac{α(α-1)...(α-k+1)}{k!}=(-1)^k\frac{(-α+k-1)...(-α+1)(-α)}{k!}=(-1)^k\binom{-α+k-1}{k}
$$

---

so that combined
$$
1=(1-x)^{α}(1-x)^{-α}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{α-1+k}{k}(1-x)^{α}x^k
$$

Comment: I don't know how can you solve my problem from it. Pls show me more detail.

Comment: @phuong: If you cannot deduce the answer to your question from the answer LutzL has provided, you may want to consider a paid tutoring service.